# Is there a "snot-nosed kid" trope?

Tags: tropes

I can think of several anime series with recurring characters who I would classify as "snot-nosed kids".  Two sympathetic, recurring, characters are Udon from *Naruto* and Komugi from *Hunter x Hunter*.  Is there an actual trope for this character trait, and if so, what is it meant to imply?  To me (American), the trait merely means someone I don't really want to look at.

Surely there is more than that, though.  Sort of like a bloody nose often means the character is somehow sexually embarrassed.

Comment: Not exactly the same, but there is a [Snot Bubble](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SnotBubble) trope.